# Activate save-as or open pop-up box for video files

Tags: .htaccess, browser, http-headers, server-side, content-disposition

In my .htaccess did I manage to activate a pop-up box with save-as and open options for a file download, those files being images, jpg, jpeg, png etc. This works perfectly.

Here the code:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.jpg$">
      Header append Content-Disposition "attachment;"
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.jpeg$">
      Header append Content-Disposition "attachment;"
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.png$">
      Header append Content-Disposition "attachment;"
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.ogv$">
      Header append Content-Disposition "attachment;"
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.mov$">
      Header append Content-Disposition "attachment;"
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.avi$">
      Header append Content-Disposition "attachment;"
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.mp4$">
      Header append Content-Disposition "attachment;"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Now I want to have the same feature for VIDEO files (ogv, avi, mp4, etc.), and I added the code the same way, but it does not work for video files, how to make this solution work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AddType` to force the downloads:

```bsh
AddType application/octet-stream .ogv
AddType application/octet-stream .avi
AddType application/octet-stream .mp4
```

Alternatively, you can use this method, and incorporate the other file types you've alrady done:

```bsh
<FilesMatch "\.(jpe?g|png|ogv|mov|avi|mp4)$" >
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header add Content-Disposition "attachment"
</FilesMatch>
```

This is also an option you can try:

```bsh
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|png|ogv|mov|avi|mp4)$ - [T=application/octet-stream]
```

**Regarding Firefox:** It appears that FF requires the filename to be set. This is the best way I can think of doing it - and it appears to work perfectly:

```bsh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+).(jpe?g|png|ogv|mov|avi|mp4)$ - [env=filename:$1.$2]

<FilesMatch "\.(jpe?g|png|ogv|mov|avi|mp4)$" >
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header add Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=%{filename}e"
</FilesMatch>
```

Here, we're checking to see if the request is for an existing file, and if the file ends with a certain extension. If so, set an environment variable called `filename`, and pass it to `Header add`. Quite magical, really. Firefox is quite strict with a few other things too - so this is good to know.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks. It works in Chrome and IE, but not in latest Firefox. The video files in Firefox bring a soup of all scrambled code in my browser when clicking download (image files work well though). Any ideas?

Comment: Have also added a third option. I must say, though - Firefox can be a tad strange sometimes.

Comment: Hi Mike, no, unfortunately Header set doesnt work either in Firefox.

Comment: No, 3rd solution also doesnt work with Firefox, a browser that makes me really wana pull out my hair!

Comment: Seems I've found the problem - please see my update.

Comment: Hi Mike, I implemented your last code lines solution, and now I get this: "You have chosen to open (null) which is application/octet-stream." What should FF do with this file? I think I am missing something...

Comment: the above "null" "error" message does not occur all the time, in other instances your solution works perfectly. But FF is behaving weirdly! Anyways, thanks a lot for your help... +1.

Comment: Strange indeed - may be a performance issue, not sure. Worked 100% for me.